# JQuery UI Tabs + Wordpress issues

Tags: jquery, wordpress, user-interface, tabs

I am trying to integrate JQuery tabs with my WordPress blog, to replace old HTML Navigation menu. I am half way there but not quiet...

Take a look for yourself: http://www.isahat.com

1. The template breaks right away since the first button of the Tab menu is linked to **index.php** like so:

   ```
   <div id="tabs">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="/info/">Info</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. The second tab menu shows my **Info** page just fine, but on top of everything else. My home page and everything else gets shifted down to make room for **Info** page.
3. And why after clicking on any article or even the tab link, my tab menu disappears and all my navigation links turn into a bullet list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tabs don't work at all in Safari, and when the tabs do work, your code errors have something to do with the content shifting: [[Invalid]Markup Validation of  isahat.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//isahat.com/%23tabs-4&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

You also have a script from GoDaddy that is getting dumped in after your `</html>` tag. Are you on free GoDaddy hosting? That hosting conflicts with Wordpress and disrupts page display.

Comment: I understand what is the problem now, songdogtech. It just won't work like this. To fix this problem I'd have to mess around with the major portion of the code between multiple .php files, which is a hassle. I'll just drop WordPress and write my own website from scratch and integrate with JQuery. And yes I am using free GoDaddy hosting.